# Find the (likely) git commit from which a version was branched

Tags: git, diff, file-comparison

I have a directory containing files that were originally checked out from Git, then modified. Unfortunately, I don't have any of the Git metadata. I'd like to know what Git commit that directory's content branched from.

The problem isn't fully defined, of course, since similar changes might have been applied on both sides, or the directory content could be a mix-and-match of different versions. However, I don't really care exactly how that tree came to be. What I want is to get a compact view of what was modified from the original. So I'd like to identify a commit that (nearly) minimizes the diff between that commit and the directory's content.

I can iterate over commits around the right time period and do something like `diff | wc -l`, but there may be better heuristics. Binary files are unlikely to be relevant in my case.

What's a good way of identifying the closest Git commit to a particular modified version? Is there a ready-made tool for that?

Comment: Is the history linear, or do you want to explore branches?

Comment: @StephenKitt In this specific case, I'm pretty sure I know which branch the data came from.

Comment: If you still have some build artifacts that were created when .git
magic directory was present it might be possible to find SHA1 of the commit
embedded somewhere as it might be used to print `--version`. `git
describe` is most often used for this purpose.

Comment: You could also start from looking at the file that most probably was
being changed the least such as README.{md,rst,txt,etc.} or Makefile
etc., check if the version you have is the same as on the tip of the
branch and if it's not find the newest commit when it still was -
that will allow you to ignore all newer commits. Regardless, I believe
that `git-bisect` might be useful for that kind of job.

Comment: There's a command named [`range-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff) in the documentation, which can compare commits across different ranges. I'm not familiar with this myself (hence the comment), but it looks like a promising lead.

Comment: This is just an idea, no idea if it will work: Can you use the bisect tool (to binary search the repo), then some automated test to count add, remove, and changes. If the checkout removes from the repo-revision, then the checkout is probably earlier. If it adds the probably later. You may have to combine the simplistic binary-search with an optimisation-search strategy (more than minimal samples).